# error de prueba de una app (android) en dispositivos físicos

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Ayuda por favor. Tengo un problema a la hora de probar mi app (android) en dispositivos físicos. He creado un activity simple con cuatros imágenes y dos botones, la parte lógica no escrito nada todavía. El minSdkVersion 22.

Tengo tres celulares uno Lg k4 con android 6, un Huawei y3 con android 5.2 y un Samsung j5 prime con android 7.
Al momento de probarlo en los tres dispositivos solo funciona en el Samsung y en los otros dos solo sale el icono de la app y cuando presiono abre una pantalla y sale un mensaje "la aplicacion Nombre se ha detenido".

Nota: Al momento de ejecutar la app, el android studio lo compila bien y no sale ningún error.
He probado un app con un hola mundo en los tres celulares y funciona ok en los tres celulares.

Comment: Hola comparte el Logcat :D, donde te muestra el error para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Hola Carlos, me podrías decir porfa como lo comparto el Logcast?

Comment: claro, edita tu post y pon alli el Logcat que te sale en android studio

Comment: Carlos, son muchas lineas para pegar, no hay un otra forma de compartir

Comment: no hay problema solo pega todo lo que esta en rojo :D